# Rails 4 - Render different form partials in new action from new.js.erb

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, partial-views

In my application, I have a `Post` model. When the user is adding a post, they can select 4 different types of post. Basically, each *type* has different fields in the form.

*For example: **Type 1** has only images, **Type 2** has only description, **Type 3** has only title, while **Type 4** has all fields active.

Currently, when the user is clicking on **Add New Post**, they need to select a post type *(from a bootstrap modal)* and I add a `param type` to the link and this will be added to:

```
= f.hidden_field :post_type, value: params[:type]
```

In my `posts#new` I have:

```
- if params[:type].present?
  - if params[:type].to_i == 1
    = render 'posts/form_partials/only_image'
  - elsif params[:type].to_i == 2
    = render 'posts/form_partials/only_description'
  - elsif params[:type].to_i == 3
    = render 'posts/form_partials/only_title'
  - elsif params[:type].to_i == 4
    = render 'posts/form_partials/all_fields'
```

But I don't like the way I currently do it and prefer to load the correct partial from inside the form when they selected a `post_type`.

I tried to have a `new.js.erb`, but it doesn't fire up at all.

```
## PostsController#new
def new
  @post = Post.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end

## new.js.erb (testing if I get contact)
$('button').click(function(){
  console.log("New Action fired up");
});
```

What is the best way to go with and what I can improve to load the correct partial from form when user have selected `post_type`.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for this is to add 4 different `partials` in your `view`, and do this in your controller:

```
- if params[:type].present?
  - if params[:type].to_i == 1
    = render 'posts/form_partials/only_image'
  - elsif params[:type].to_i == 2
    = render 'posts/form_partials/only_description'
  - elsif params[:type].to_i == 3
    = render 'posts/form_partials/only_title'
  - elsif params[:type].to_i == 4
    = render 'posts/form_partials/all_fields'
```

and render the *correct* partials in your `new` view